# PivotTable.JS Callback implementation problem

Tags: pivottable.js

I have implemented PivotTable.JS in Filemaker and it works great. I've added the callback code and that function seems to be working when I click on a cell. When click on the cell I get the dialog "Message from webpage", I assume I still need to add some code to show the records that makes up the content of the click cell. What would be the approach to show the records, unfortunately I am not java script savvy.

```
$("#output").pivotUI(
  $.pivotUtilities.tipsData, {
    cols: ["Quarter Latest"],
    rows: ["Customer"],
    vals: ["Wt Forecast"],
    aggregatorName: "Sum",
  rendererName: "Table",
    renderers: $.extend(
         $.pivotUtilities.renderers,
      $.pivotUtilities.c3_renderers,
$.pivotUtilities.export_renderers
    ),
rendererOptions: {
                    table: {
                        clickCallback: function(e, value, filters, pivotData){
                            var names = [];
                            pivotData.forEachMatchingRecord(filters,
                                function(record){ names.push(record.Name); });
                            alert(names.join("\n"));
                        }
                    }
                }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you are pushing into the array 'names' a field 'Name' that is not available in your recordset.
You can access de complete json returned on the clickCallBack by making a small change to your code.

```
$("#output").pivotUI(
  $.pivotUtilities.tipsData, {
    cols: ["Quarter Latest"],
    rows: ["Customer"],
    vals: ["Wt Forecast"],
    aggregatorName: "Sum",
  rendererName: "Table",
    renderers: $.extend(
         $.pivotUtilities.renderers,
      $.pivotUtilities.c3_renderers,
$.pivotUtilities.export_renderers
    ),
rendererOptions: {
                    table: {
                        clickCallback: function(e, value, filters, pivotData){
                            var fullData = [];
                            pivotData.forEachMatchingRecord(filters,
                                function(record){ fullData.push(record); });
                            console.log(fullData);
                        }
                    }
                }
  });
```

Perhaps you can later pass that JSON to another function and build a table.